# Constructing a graph in Magma

Tags: magma-cas

I am trying to construct a simple graph in MAGMA and can't figure out how to get the syntax right. My code is below:

```
triples := { <a,b,c> : a, b, c in GF(7) | a^2 + b^2 - c^2 eq 0 };
G := Graph< triples | {<3, 3, 2>, <1, 6, 3>} >;
```

The error I get is:

```
Runtime error in Graph< ... >: RHS argument 1 - Tuples in sequence must be <vertex, {vertices}>
```

I am just trying this as a dummy example with one edge. To me, my syntax looks like the examples in the online handbook, only instead of creating numbered vertices I've labelled my vertices with the set `triples`. I've checked that both

```
<3,3,2> in triples;
<1,6,3> in triples;
```

evaluate to true. Can someone help me understand what's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Magma just doesn't recognize these tuples as elements of your vertex set. This can be fixed by coercing them - ex `{ triples | <3,3,2>, <1,6,3>}` to define your edge.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help!